# Saving the result of a telnet request as a text document

Tags: telnet, save

So, say I run "telnet google.com 80\rGET / HTTP/1.0\r", is there any way I could save the ensuing HTTP data?

Is it possible to do in bash? If not, Perl?

Comment: why not just use wget or curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) command seems to meet your requirements.  Once you start it, all the terminal output from that session gets saved to a file.  But for the specific task you mentioned,
I'd use `wget` or `curl` rather than messing around with `script`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29).

```
telnet google.com 80 | tee output.txt
```